# How does GitHub decide what default branch to show?

Tags: git, github, branch

When you visit a project on GitHub, it always shows the `master` branch. How does GitHub decide what branch to show (there does not need to be a `master` branch)?

Comment: @thejh, It's on topic as it's a question about "software tools commonly used by programmers", although I'm not sure it's been adequately researched.

Comment: @CodieCodeMonkey Yes, I didn't do a close-vote. Just wanted to point out that this probably isn't the best place to ask this question.

Comment: @thejh, Ah yes, agree with you then.

Comment: @thejh No need to be rude, but yes, it might have been a better idea.

Comment: Off topic since it's about a profile/repo setting on the web app instead of programming with it like via the API or pushing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Github help](https://help.github.com/) is your friend, here's a section that explains well how to [Set the default branch](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-the-default-branch).

1. **Open** the repository page
2. **Click** the Settings button
3. **Change** the default branch

Answer (score 3):

There's a 'default branch' selector in the Settings page for each repository, it looks there. By default Github repos have a master branch when created.